# Scala Adding many column in dataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
private def example(channelRollups: Seq[String]): Seq[(String, String)]={
seqOfElement.flatMap(first => seqOfElement.
      filter(second => first.toLowerCase() < second.toLowerCase()).
      map((first, _)))

}
def addProductCol(df: DataFrame, cols: (String, String)): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn(s"${cols._1}_${cols._2}", df(cols._1) * df(cols._2))
}

def addAllProductCols(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
 colPairs = example(exampleSeq)
  colPairs.foldLeft(df)(addProductCol)
}
```

Output

```
colPairs = Seq(("left", "right"), ("middle", "right"))
+----+------+-----+
|left|middle|right|
+----+------+-----+
|   2|     3|    5|
|   7|    11|   13|
|  17|    19|   23|
+----+------+-----+

+----+------+-----+----------+------------+
|left|middle|right|left_right|middle_right|
+----+------+-----+----------+------------+
|   2|     3|    5|        10|          15|
|   7|    11|   13|        91|         143|
|  17|    19|   23|       391|         437|
+----+------+-----+----------+------------+
```

Instead of directly adding column into DataFrame , Can we modify into DataFrame => DataFrame or we can say a transform??

```
 def example2 : DataFrame => DataFrame = {
    dataFrame => {
      dataFrame.
        withColumn(Column, when(col(ORDER_DATETIME_KEY).isNotNull, 1).otherwise(0))
    }
  }
```

So basically I want to make the first example like the exmaple2 in which I will return dataType as DataFrame => DataFrame not as DataFrame

Comment: Spark DataFrame has transform method: https://kb.databricks.com/data/chained-transformations.html

Comment: @boris-azanov Hi I just want to change the return type as DataFrame => DataFrame instead of returning a DataFrame so can u suggest code changes ?

Comment: for why? you can use your `addAllProductCols` into transform method:
`df.transform(addAllProductCols) //should return DataFrame with product columns`

Comment: Please minimize your code sample to reflect the problem. If you could show actual vs. expected output that would be ideal quesion