# Scala making a function return type as DataFrame=> DataFrame not as DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
private def example(channelRollups: Seq[String]): Seq[(String, String)]={
seqOfElement.flatMap(first => seqOfElement.
      filter(second => first.toLowerCase() < second.toLowerCase()).
      map((first, _)))

}
def addProductCol(df: DataFrame, cols: (String, String)): DataFrame = {
  df.withColumn(s"${cols._1}_${cols._2}", df(cols._1) * df(cols._2))
}

def addAllProductCols(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
 colPairs = example(exampleSeq)
  colPairs.foldLeft(df)(addProductCol)
}
```

Output

```
colPairs = Seq(("left", "right"), ("middle", "right"))
+----+------+-----+
|left|middle|right|
+----+------+-----+
|   2|     3|    5|
|   7|    11|   13|
|  17|    19|   23|
+----+------+-----+

+----+------+-----+----------+------------+
|left|middle|right|left_right|middle_right|
+----+------+-----+----------+------------+
|   2|     3|    5|        10|          15|
|   7|    11|   13|        91|         143|
|  17|    19|   23|       391|         437|
+----+------+-----+----------+------------+
```

Instead of directly adding column into DataFrame , Can we modify into DataFrame => DataFrame or we can say a transform??

```
 def example2 : DataFrame => DataFrame = {
    dataFrame => {
      dataFrame.
        withColumn(Column, when(col(ORDER_DATETIME_KEY).isNotNull, 1).otherwise(0))
    }
  }
```

So basically I want to make the first example like the example2 in which I will return dataType as `DataFrame => DataFrame` not as DataFrame

Comment: Why `channelRollups` parameter isn't used in `example` method? Should it be instead of `seqOfElement` in the body of the method?

Comment: because emaple2 is just an example there is no logicall similarity between them . only I want to change the return type of example 1 as DataFrame=> DataFrame instaed of DataFrame . please Ignore example 2 if u r confusing

Comment: Is this different from your previous question? It has different title, but exactly same contents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61516373/scala-adding-many-column-in-dataframe